# how to sale products inside the ios app without using in app purchase

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi Is their any other way available to integrate payment process and buy products inside IOS application without using the in app purchase, how to sale products inside the ios app without in app purchase?

Comment: Physical or digital goods?

Comment: if you have integration of server then you can use paypal for payment and have records on your server for selling stuff.

Paypal sdk for iOS is easily available and easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

you can integrate payment gateways like [stripe](https://stripe.com/), paypal which are available for mobile platform. But if you trying to replace in-app purchase because of Apple cut 30%, you most likely to get rejected by Apple.

You can use payment gateways if you are selling digital goods, may be a e-commerce app or something.

Comment: If I recall, digital goods tend to fall in this category, while physical goods are usually more safe.

Comment: From Apple documentation "Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the App will be rejected" According to this they clearly mention don't use In-app purchase for physical goods and also didn't tell that you can't use any other payment system..

Comment: thanks i have used paypal but apple has rejected by application so what can i do now?

Comment: what type of product you are selling?